# Sitewide autocomplete-search with the apostrophe-search module

Tags: apostrophe-cms

i already saw the 2 questions about cursors and autocomplete and tried to fuse the information i got from the questions and the "Working with Cursors" Documentation

I tried to implement a sitewide search, that autocompletes the current query.

```
app.js

'apostrophe-search': {
        types: [
            'brands',
            'news',
            'people'
        ],
        filters: [
            {
                name: 'brands',
                label: 'Brands'
            },
            {
                name: 'people',
                label: 'People'
            },
            {
                name: 'news',
                label: 'News'
            }
        ],
        construct: function(self, options) {
            var cursor = self.apos.docs.find(req, {})
                .queryToFilters(req.query, 'public')
                .perPage(self.perPage);
            cursor.autocomplete(req.query);
        }
    },
```

And my Search looks like this

```
<div class="search_container">
        <form class="navbar-form" method="GET" action="/search">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" data-apos-search-field value="{{ data.query.autocomplete | e }}" name="autocomplete">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

The req in docs.find() gives me an error that its not defined. Is there something else that needs to be added after the construct that i'm missing?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @tylerPope nope, it remains unresolved.